# Authorization in .NET Core 6 returns 400?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new in .NET Core so I decided to seek help here.

I am having trouble creating the Authentication Functionality of my Web Application.

The problem is, I am getting `Error Response 400`.  and  if change some of the configuration in my Program.cs like removing this line of code,

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["jwt"];
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
```

It will return `Error Response 401`.

Here is my code in my Program.cs

```
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Dev_Environment")));

        builder.Services.AddIdentity<LoginModel, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["jwt"];
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Hashing:ValidIssuer"],
                ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Hashing:ValidAudience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Hashing:SecretKey"]))
            };
        });

        builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

            options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
        });

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Authentication}/{action=Login}/{id?}"); 

        app.Run();
```

I have create a DashboardController with the Attribute `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Here is my `AuthenticationController` creating a JWT Token for Authorizaiton purposes.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(LoginModel userCredential, string returnURL)
        {
            systemLogic = new AuthenticationLogic();

            if (userCredential != null)
            {
                userCredential.Email = hasher.Encrypt(userCredential.Email);
                userCredential.Password = hasher.Encrypt(clearText: userCredential.Password);
            }

            userInput = new UserInput();

#pragma warning disable CS8604 // Possible null reference argument.
            userInput[typeof(LoginModel).FullName] = userCredential;
#pragma warning restore CS8604 // Possible null reference argument.
            systemResult = systemLogic.ExecuteProcess(configuration, userInput);

            if (systemResult.ResultCode == SystemResult.SUCCESS)
            {
                LoginModel? userInfo = systemResult[typeof(LoginModel).FullName] as LoginModel;

                Claim[] claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, hasher.Decrypt(userInfo.Email)) };

                SymmetricSecurityKey secretKey = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Hashing:SecretKey"]));

                SigningCredentials signinCredentials = new(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                JwtSecurityToken tokenOptions = new(
                    issuer: configuration["Hashing:ValidIssuer"],
                    audience: configuration["Hashing:ValidAudience"],
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                    signingCredentials: signinCredentials);

                string tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);


                // Response.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenString);

                Response.Cookies.Append("jwt", tokenString, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                    Secure = true,
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
                });

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnURL)) 
                { 
                    return Redirect(returnURL);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
            }
            else
            { 
                return View(userCredential);
            } 
        }
```

What am I doing wrong on this and why I am getting 401 and 400?

I already check the `context.Request.Cookies["jwt"]` after logging in and there is a token. And still the response will be 400.

Comment: Why you return 401 after removing the configurations: it would read jwt token from request cookie as you configured,if you removed the codes related ,it would read jwt token from header Authorization : Bearer  yourtoken;

Comment: When it comes to 400 error,it means the model you passed to controller doesn't match what it expected, you have to show more details of your DashboardController and what you passed to it

Comment: Since you could get the 400 error , it means your authentication part works well,you don't have to modify the codes related with it

Comment: @RuikaiFeng, Actually, this is in my controller.    `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Comment: @RuikaiFeng, That is all in the Controller. I mean, I am just testing my AuthenticationController if it will redirect to DashboardController using the JWT Token. yet its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your comments and i think the 400 error was caused by `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute .If you add the attr on the controller, when you send a get request, it would also expect an AntiForgeryToken .For your requirement,it should be `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]`  to protect all post endpoints

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0#automatically-validate-antiforgery-tokens-for-unsafe-http-methods-only-1) related for more details